# Reseting Column names and removing Indices of a Transposed table

Tags: pandas, dataframe

***Expected Output is a  Horizontal table(with stacked tables) with named headers on the left and no/hidden indices.) :***

[image]

```
Original dataframes:
r1 =       
     Stock   %Change
0     RELIANCE  (-0.62%)
1          TCS  (-1.68%)
2     HDFCBANK  (-0.77%)
3    ICICIBANK  (-0.72%)

r2 =        
    Stock   %Change
0           LT  (-0.27%)
1      HCLTECH   (-1.9%)
2   ASIANPAINT  (-1.48%)
3     AXISBANK  (-0.41%)
```

How to reset vertical tables and merge into a stacked horizontal table one above the other with custom HeaderNames on left and no/hidden Indices so that all the cells can be displayed in one view(No Scroll)?

```
r_concat simply returns the concatenated table without the renaming columns 

in:    r_concat = pd.concat([r1.transpose(),r2.transpose()],axis=0,ignore_index=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'0':'Stock','1':'%Chg','2':'Stock','3':'%Chg'}).set_index('Stock')
    
out:
    r_concat =   
           0         1           2          3           4          5        6   
    0  RELIANCE       TCS    HDFCBANK  ICICIBANK  HINDUNILVR        ITC     INFY   
    1  (-1.39%)   (0.03%)    (-0.65%)   (-0.15%)     (0.29%)   (-0.78%)  (0.38%)   
    2        LT   HCLTECH  ASIANPAINT   AXISBANK      MARUTI  SUNPHARMA    TITAN   
    3  (-0.86%)  (-0.91%)      (0.1%)    (0.01%)    (-1.44%)   (-1.43%)  (0.32%)
```

Comment: It's possible that column names are int type not str.

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Comment: @jezrael Expected Output Table Image has been attached

Comment: @srt111 - Can you check my edited answer?

Comment: So need only `r_concat = pd.concat([r1.T,r2.T])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used ***Join & Transpose*** and got the expected Horizontal table(with stacked tables) with named headers on the left and no/hidden indices.

In:

```
  r_join = r1.join(r2,lsuffix='_0', rsuffix='_1')
    r_join =r_join.reset_index().set_index('Stock_0').drop(['index'], axis=1).transpose()
```

Out:

```
 r_join =
     Stock_0    RELIANCE       TCS    HDFCBANK ICICIBANK HINDUNILVR        ITC 
    %Change_0  (-0.55%)  (-1.75%)    (-1.21%)  (-0.73%)   (-0.57%)   (-0.02%)   
    Stock_1          LT   HCLTECH  ASIANPAINT  AXISBANK     MARUTI  SUNPHARMA   
    %Change_1  (-0.48%)   (-1.9%)    (-1.84%)  (-0.54%)    (0.04%)   (-1.16%)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is unclear but you might want:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([r_concat.iloc[1::2].to_numpy().ravel()],
                   columns=r_concat.iloc[::2].to_numpy().ravel()
                   )
```

Output:

```
   RELIANCE      TCS  HDFCBANK ICICIBANK HINDUNILVR       ITC     INFY        LT   HCLTECH ASIANPAINT AXISBANK    MARUTI SUNPHARMA    TITAN
0  (-1.39%)  (0.03%)  (-0.65%)  (-0.15%)    (0.29%)  (-0.78%)  (0.38%)  (-0.86%)  (-0.91%)     (0.1%)  (0.01%)  (-1.44%)  (-1.43%)  (0.32%)
```

Or maybe:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'stock': r_concat.iloc[::2].to_numpy().ravel(),
                    'change': r_concat.iloc[1::2].to_numpy().ravel()
                    })
```

Output:

```
         stock    change
0     RELIANCE  (-1.39%)
1          TCS   (0.03%)
2     HDFCBANK  (-0.65%)
3    ICICIBANK  (-0.15%)
4   HINDUNILVR   (0.29%)
5          ITC  (-0.78%)
6         INFY   (0.38%)
7           LT  (-0.86%)
8      HCLTECH  (-0.91%)
9   ASIANPAINT    (0.1%)
10    AXISBANK   (0.01%)
11      MARUTI  (-1.44%)
12   SUNPHARMA  (-1.43%)
13       TITAN   (0.32%)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Stock': r_concat.iloc[::2].to_numpy().ravel(),
                             'change': r_concat.iloc[1::2].to_numpy().ravel()},
                            orient='index')
```

Output:

```
              0        1         2          3           4         5        6         7         8           9         10        11         12       13
Stock   RELIANCE      TCS  HDFCBANK  ICICIBANK  HINDUNILVR       ITC     INFY        LT   HCLTECH  ASIANPAINT  AXISBANK    MARUTI  SUNPHARMA    TITAN
change  (-1.39%)  (0.03%)  (-0.65%)   (-0.15%)     (0.29%)  (-0.78%)  (0.38%)  (-0.86%)  (-0.91%)      (0.1%)   (0.01%)  (-1.44%)   (-1.43%)  (0.32%)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue...I have attached the expected image of the required Table .It needs to be a Horizontal table with headers on the left and no indices.

Comment: @srt111 you cannot have no indices (columns names) in a DataFrame, you can remove them during export or "hide" them by replacing with empty strings but there are still there. If you want a wide format with, see my update. I believe my first solution is the best approach, having the stocks as column names makes more sense

Comment: This solution results in a never ending scroll ,to avoid this the tables have been stacked ..... I have updated the code with original data .

Comment: @srt111 what you want is unclear, do you want to keep your table and just change the index? `r_concat.index = (r_concat.index%2).map(dict(enumerate(['Stock', '%Change'])))` or `r_concat.index = np.array(['Stock', '%Change'])[np.arange(len(r_concat))%2]`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
r_concat = pd.concat([r1.T,r2.T])
```

Or:

```
r_concat = pd.concat([r1,r2], axis=1).T
```

---

```
print (r_concat)
                0         1           2          3
Stock    RELIANCE       TCS    HDFCBANK  ICICIBANK
%Change  (-0.62%)  (-1.68%)    (-0.77%)   (-0.72%)
Stock          LT   HCLTECH  ASIANPAINT   AXISBANK
%Change  (-0.27%)   (-1.9%)    (-1.48%)   (-0.41%)
```

For write to file or display without columns names use:

```
r_concat.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False)

print (r_concat.to_string(header=False))
```